# Change member-typedef depending on template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

I have this problem here that I can’t figure out how to solve. I want a template class that takes an integer as template parameter and sets the template parameters for another class accordingly:

```
template <int T>
class Solver
{

  public:

    #if T <= 24
      typedef MyMatrix<float> Matrix;
    #else if T <= 53
      typedef MyMatrix<double> Matrix;
    #else
      typedef MyMatrix<mpreal> Matrix;
    #endif

    Matrix create();

};
```

And then calling it like this:

```
Solver<53>::Matrix m = Solver<53>::create();
```

How can I do something like this? At the moment with the code above, the compiler complaints that it doesn't know "Matrix", so I'm not sure if you can use the preprocessor on template parameters.

Comment: Where is `MyMatrix` defined?

Comment: Preprocessor conditions are evaluated before compiling so what you're trying now won't work (T is not defined as far as the preprocessor is concerned).

Comment: MyMatrix is a simple matrix class defined somewhere else and takes a type as parameter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### INTRODUCTION

Since you'd like `S<N>::Matrix` to yield a different type depending on the *N* passed, you will need to use some sort of *meta template programming*. The question is currently tagged with *preprocessor*, and the snippet explicitly tries to use it; but that is of little to no use in this case.

When the code is being preprocessed `N` is nothing more than a name, it hasn't got a value; yet.

---

#### Solution

The description mentiones *if*, *if ... else*, and *else*; and we are dealing with types.. looking through [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) it seems like [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) would be a perfect match!

```
std::conditional<condition, type-if-true, type-if-false>::type;
```

<sup>**Note**: Depending on whether the expression found in `condition` yields *true*, or *false*, `::type` will be a *typedef*  for either *type-if-true*, or *type-if-false*.</sup>

---

Let's write a sample implementation:

```
#include <type_traits>
```

```
template <int N>
class Solver
{
  public:
    typedef typename std::conditional<
      /*    */ (N <= 24),
      /* y? */ MyMatrix<float>,
      /* n? */ typename std::conditional<(N <= 53), MyMatrix<double>, MyMatrix<mpreal>>::type
    >::type matrix_type;

  ...
};
```

```
int main () {
  Solver<53>::matrix_type a; // Matrix<double>
  Solver<10>::matrix_type b; // Matrix<float>
  Solver<99>::matrix_type c; // Matrix<mpreal>
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Learned about `std::conditional` today.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks Filip, you made my work a lot easier.

Comment: @RSahu: Wow, me too. It's so simple! :) Just a template specification for the `false` case. Very cool: `template <bool _Bp, class _If, class _Then> struct conditional {typedef _If type;};`              
`template <class _If, class _Then> struct conditional<false, _If, _Then> {typedef _Then type;}; `

Comment: `std::conditional` requires C++11. Do you have anything for C++03 and above? While GCC 4.8 nd 4.9 is alive and well we need to support C++03.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `std::conditional` for this, although whether you should be doing this in the first place is another kettle of fish:

```
template<int T>
class Solver
{
  std::conditional_t<
    T <= 24,
    MyMatrix<float>,
    std::conditional_t<
      T <= 53,
      MyMatrix<double>,
      MyMatrix<mpreal>
    >
  > Matrix;
};
```

You'll need to use `std::conditional` and `::type` instead of `conditional_t` if your compiler doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use the preprocessor on template parameters.

The preprocessor is just doing very simple string processing on your input source. It has no glue about types and I think it is run as the very first step while first processing the file and collecting all the includes. Templates are something the compiler itself takes care of. At this point the preprocessor has finished already.

A similar question has been asked here: 
[Use a template parameter in a preprocessor directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904376/use-a-template-parameter-in-a-preprocessor-directive)

Comment: Thanks. Any other way of doing it? In the link you posted, the last answer provides sort of a solution, but then you have to add a subclass for every value of the parameter and I want to specify one class for an entire range.

Comment: Specification like that is exactly how `std::conditional` works, they just package it up for you so you don't need to do it yourself! :)