# C++: How to work with data type of parameter in member function template

Tags: c++

I've to do activities in my template based on type of class I get as parameter:

In Class.h

```
class SomeClass;
class SomeOtherClass;

class Class 
{
public:
    template <typename T> void function(T value);
};
```

In Class.cpp

```
template<typename T> void Class::function(T value) 
{
    // Whole lots of common code here

    if (T == SomeClass)
    {
       // Do something by casting value to SomeClass
       SomeClass* ptrSomeClassObj = (SomeClass*) &value;
       ptrSomeClassObj->MemberFunctionOfSomeClass();
    }
    else
    {
       // Do something else
    }

    // Whole lots of common code here
}
```

Now I've these questions:

1. Here `if (T == SomeClass)` is not correct syntax. How shall I do this?
2. Type casting of `T` the way I've done doesn't give me any syntax error. But is this appropriate to do like this? I believe C++ has better ways.

**Update:**
Not really looking for [Template specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26359438/c-compare-template-type-during-compile-time) because it would replicate lots of common code (as mentioned in code above) in specialized functions.

Comment: Also use template specialization instead of `if (T == SomeClass)`.

Comment: `template<> void Class::function(SomeClass)
 value) 
{ // code for SomeClass ... }`

Comment: Also, not sure how is this duplicate? The other question is generic about template implementation. This one is very specific I am asking.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Implementation splitting *will* be a problem, but is not the point of this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Compare template type during compile time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26359438/c-compare-template-type-during-compile-time)

Comment: @Christophe: Please see update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to move the code depending on the actual type of `T` to a second member (or static) function wich you can then overload, passing any values resulting from the common code as parameters (`someParam`):

```
class SomeClass;
class SomeOtherClass;

class Class 
{
public:
    void typeDependent(SomeClass value, int someParam);
    template <typename T> void typeDependent(T value, int someParam);

    template <typename T> void function(T value);
};

void Class::typeDependent(SomeClass value, int someParam) 
{
    value->MemberFunctionOfSomeClass(someParam);
}

template<typename T> void Class::typeDependent(T value, int someParam) 
{
    // Do something else
}

template<typename T> void Class::function(T value) 
{
    int someParam = 123; // Whole lots of common code here
    typeDependent(value, someParam);
    // Whole lots of common code here
}
```

This allows you to call functions that only exist for the SomeClass type without casting. Note that I didn't use template specialization but overloading - Using specialization for function templates is generally a bad idea due to their complicated resolution rules.

If you insist on writing this distiction as a conditional, you can use the `std::is_same` template (Requires C++11):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> void Class::function(T value) 
{
    if (std::is_same<T, SomeClass>::value)
    {
         // Do something
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

This will require you to use a cast like you did in the original post as the function will not compile for `T != SomeClass` otherwise.

Comment: Brilliant! This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the most straightforward way to do this is overloading and delegating the work:

```
class SomeClass;
class SomeOtherClass;

class Class 
{
public:
    template <typename T> void function(T value);

    template <typename T> void function_detail(T value);
    void function_detail(SomeClass value);
};

template<typename T> void Class::function(T value) 
{
    // Whole lots of common code here

    function_detail(value);

    // Whole lots of common code here
}

template<typename T> void Class::function_detail(T value) 
{
    // Do something else.
}

void Class::function_detail(SomeClass value) 
{
    value.MemberFunctionOfSomeClass();
}
```